# how does this node class works in doubly linked list

Tags: typescript, data-structures, linked-list, nodes, doubly-linked-list

In class Node, next is of type Node or null. By this, we can only assign Node or null to next

```
class Node {
  value: any;
  next: Node | null;
  prev: Node | null;

  constructor(value: any) {
    this.value = value;
    this.next = null;
    this.prev = null;
  }
}
```

But I see that in the push function, in this line "this.tail!.next = newNode;" we have assigned just the newNode reference to the next property, here newNode is just a reference it won't have value, or next or prev values as we have in Node class.

```
push(value: any) {
    const newNode = new Node(value);
    if (this.length === 0) {
      this.head = newNode;
      this.tail = newNode;
    } else {
      this.tail!.next = newNode;
      newNode.prev = this.tail;
      this.tail = newNode;
    }
    this.length++;
    return this;
  }
```

I really can't able to understand, How just only a reference can be given next of type Node, instead of Node that contains value, next, and prev properties.

Comment: In typescript (and in javascript) there's no distinction between references and values like in C++. Every object is accessed through a reference. The declaration `aNode: Node` is fully compatible with the assignment `aNode = new Node(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> here `newNode` is just a reference it wont have value, or next or prev values as we have in Node class.

In TypeScript objects are always handled as references. There is no `struct` kind of variable for a `Node`, like you would have in C. When in TypeScript/JavaScript we speak of "object", it is inferred that we deal with a reference. The dot operator really corresponds to `->` in C. The dot operator in C (to use on `struct` variables) has no counterpart in TypeScript/JavaScript as it doesn't have such typed variables.

`newNode` references an object that was initialised by the constructor, with `value`, `next`, and `prev` properties.

The `tail.next` property is indeed assigned a reference, and that is what is expected.

For instance, let's say we already have a list with one node having value 1, then we could picture it like this:

```
 list
  ↓
┌───────────┐   ┌────────────┐
│ head: ───────►│ prev: null │
│ tail: ───────►│ value: 0   │
│ length: 1 │   │ next: null │
└───────────┘   └────────────┘
```

If now `list.push(2)` is called, we first get the `Node` constructor running with `new Node(2)`, which initialises the object's properties, and returns the object (reference) to be assigned to `newNode`:

```
 list
  ↓
┌───────────┐   ┌────────────┐
│ head: ───────►│ prev: null │
│ tail: ───────►│ value: 0   │
│ length: 1 │   │ next: null │
└───────────┘   └────────────┘

                ┌────────────┐
                │ prev: null │
                │ value: 2   │
                │ next: null │
                └────────────┘
                   ↑
                 newNode
```

Then `this.tail!.next = newNode;` will *copy* that reference:

```
 list
  ↓
┌───────────┐   ┌────────────┐
│ head: ───────►│ prev: null │
│ tail: ───────►│ value: 0   │
│ length: 1 │   │ next: ┐    │
└───────────┘   └───────│────┘
                        ▼
                ┌────────────┐
                │ prev: null │
                │ value: 2   │
                │ next: null │
                └────────────┘
                   ↑
                 newNode
```

And `newNode.prev = this.tail;` takes care of the link in the opposite direction:

```
 list
  ↓
┌───────────┐   ┌────────────┐
│ head: ───────►│ prev: null │
│ tail: ───────►│ value: 0   │
│ length: 1 │   │ next: ┐    │
└───────────┘   └───────│────┘
                        ▼ ▲
                ┌─────────│──┐
                │ prev: ──┘  │
                │ value: 2   │
                │ next: null │
                └────────────┘
                   ↑
                 newNode
```

Finally, `this.tail = newNode;` and `this.length++` will complete the operation:

```
 list
  ↓
┌───────────┐   ┌────────────┐
│ head: ───────►│ prev: null │
│ tail: ──────┐ │ value: 0   │
│ length: 1 │ │ │ next: ┐    │
└───────────┘ │ └───────│────┘
              │         ▼ ▲
              │ ┌─────────│──┐
              └►│ prev: ──┘  │
                │ value: 2   │
                │ next: null │
                └────────────┘
                   ↑
                 newNode
```

Comment: Thanks trincot for answering my queries.